# GoLand File Cache conflict

Tags: goland

I am getting constant popups for File Cache conflict, but both memory and disk changes are the same when i go into show difference.

Hampering work in a big way. Any idea of how it can be resolved?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out the reason for the file cache conflict. Posting the answer here so maybe will help others in case of similar problems.

The conflict was being caused by one of the File Watchers I had recently configured.  `go fmt`

The issue was with the configuration.`Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher`

[image: File Watcher - go fmt]

The auto save was being triggered by a separate thread, interfering with the code being typed in the goland editor. I removed the `Auto save` option and things went back to normal

Comment: Have you manually enabled that when you created the watcher? By default, we disable that when the watcher is created via the template in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to open an issue on the issue tracker, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go, and provide the required details such as IDE logs (via Help | Collect and Show Logs in Finder), a screenshot of the configuration of File Watchers (Preferences | Tools | File Watchers). This information will help the team identify the issue quicker or they might need more information, in which case the issue tracker provides a secure way to share it.